# Android WebView and Web Browser detection

Tags: php, android, webview

EDIT:
I THINK that `browserset.setUserAgentString("SITEAPP");` should fix my issue. I will try and post results.

Just made an android app for the company i work for and I have this small issue. We use a fluid site design that works across all browsers and we wanted to make an app for our company website, but instead of rebuilding the app every time the website changes, we just used WebView to load the website..

This works great. The app looks amazing and it displays perfectly like the stock android browser. The issue now is, when they visit the site on their stock android browser they get a popup that says "Try our awesome new app" and it only shows to the browsers that output android in the user agent string. But when you open the new app we made, which loads the same webpage, the server see's android on the user agent and the people using the app ALSO see the popup? heres essentially the code:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua, 'android') !== false) {
    echo "Android Browser";
}
```

How can i make my android browser and my app browser using webview not appear the same to my server so they dont get the popup on my webapp? Is there a way to define the browser user agent in WebView settings on hte app? Or a better way to decipher if its an android phone not using my app? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the dumb question, heres my updated call for webview

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setUserAgentString("APPNAMEGOESHERE");
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.sitename.com/");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new BrowseWithin());
```

By adding the `setUserAgentString()` function I was able to change my apps user string to something different and it fixed the issue.